# Vue 3 Render Function how to set up v-model and onClicks

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Does anybody here have experience with Vue 3 Render Function? I don't know how to set up the v-model and on clicks, the documentation on Vue 3 somewhat kinda useless and lacks practical usage examples.

Maybe someone has a sample code?

Comment: please share what have you tried so far, or an example made using template syntax that you want to convert it to a render functioon

Comment: All you need is in the docs. Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Vue 3 has this doc. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#v-model

Comment: I've tried A LOT OF THINGS already.

@BoussadjraBrahim just a simple input text with a v-model functionality, that's it.

Comment: pretty sure the docs aren't clear as it supposed to be @AdamOrlov

Running JSX is a shortcut and pretty much solves my problem BUT I wanted to know how to write this thing without relying on JSX.

Comment: I have another problem, does onInput on Render get the keyCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to emulate the `v-model` directive in the render function try something like :

```
h('input', {
      value: this.test,
      onInput:(e)=> {
        this.test = e.target.value
      }

    })
```

which is equivalent to `<input v-model="test" />`

```js
const {
  createApp,
  h
} = Vue;
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      test: "Test"
    }
  },
  render() {
    return h('div', {}, [h('input', {
      value: this.test,
      onInput:(e)=> {
        this.test = e.target.value
        
      }

    }),h("h4",this.test)])
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Boussadjra Brahim

```
render() {
    self = this; // Added this

    return h('div', {}, h('input', {
        value: this.test,
        onInput(e) {
            self.test = e.target.value // Change this.test to self.test
        }
    }))
}
```

Thank you for this, I don't know why onKeyUp didn't work but onInput did.